# Android-limit/delete data from database

Tags: android

I want to retrieve data from the database. The number of data is fixed and when new data is entered the oldest data is deleted. How can I do that? What to use to erase old data and store new data? I have 25 data location and there will always be new data. 
Its android app and SQLite database is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you could implement that:
Create a column with type `NUMERIC` that stores the `long` value of a Date (`Date.getTime()`).

Then when you insert a new row, delete any row with a column value smaller than your 25th row.

```
DELETE FROM theTable
WHERE theTable.numericDate < {25thRowsNumericDate}
```